# Express app.param() middleware fires multiple times per request

Tags: node.js, express

I've supplied my `Express 4` app with some middleware to fire every time a particular set of parameters shows up in a request like so:

```
app.param(['mystic', 'donkey', 'toadstool'], function(req, res, next, param) {
  console.log(req.params);
});
```

Unfortunately if I visit `GET /:mystic/:donkey/:toadstool`. It prints out:

```
{ mystic: x, donkey: y, toadstool: z }
{ mystic: x, donkey: y, toadstool: z }
{ mystic: x, donkey: y, toadstool: z }
```

When all I want is just:

```
{ mystic: x, donkey: y, toadstool: z }
```

Is there a way to stop it from firing multiple times per req/response and still use an array at the first parameter to `app.param`?

Answer (score 1):

if you see in the [source code of app.param](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L331), you will realize that for every param in the array you put: `['mystic', 'donkey', 'toadstool']`, the callback you bind to `app.param` it will be called sequentially, in this case three times.

So there is no way you could do to have all the values in once invocation of `app.param`, probably you could grab all your params one at a time, something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.param('mystic', function(req, res, next, mystic) {
  console.log('mystic: %s', mystic);
  next();
});

app.param('donkey', function(req, res, next, donkey) {
  console.log('donkey: %s', donkey);
  next();
});

app.param('toadstool', function(req, res, next, toadstool) {
  console.log('toadstool: %s', toadstool);
  next();
});

app.get('/:mystic/:donkey/:toadstool', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hey');
});

app.listen(4040, function() {
  console.log('server up and running');
});
```